# Calculating the rolling root mean squared

Tags: python, pandas

I have a signal for Vibration, i want to smooth the signal using Root mean squared with a rolling window of 21 days. The data is in minute wise so rolling window of 21 days means 21*1440[21*24*60]. 
Is there any approach like:

```
    # Dummy approach
    df['Rolling_rms'] = df['signal'].rolling(21*1440).rms()
```

I am trying an approach by using the for loop which is way too time consuming:

```
 # Function for calculating RMS
 def rms_calc(ser):
     return np.sqrt(np.mean(ser**2))

 for i in range(0,len(signal)):
 j = 21*1440+i
 print(rms_calc(df[signal][i:j]))
```

Comment: Not what you are asking for, but scipy provides a number of filters out of the box for signal processing. Rolling windows (even with root mean squared) if not always an excellent filter. You could have a look at https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SignalSmooth.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method `apply` with a custom function:

```
df['signal'].pow(2).rolling(21*24*60).apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(x.mean()))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Further to @mykola-zotko's answer:

- there is [a `mean` method for the `rolling` object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html), which would speed this up considerably.
- I'd still use the `apply` method to get the square root; however, passing [the `raw=True` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) should also speed up the calculation.

In full:

```
df['signal'].pow(2).rolling(21*24*60).mean().apply(np.sqrt, raw=True)
```

#### Alternate method

If you want to zero-mean your data windows before calculating the RMS (which I believe is common in vibration analysis), then the calculation will be mathematically equivalent to calculating the rolling *standard deviation*. In *that* case, you can also just use [the `std` method for the `rolling` object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.std.html):

```
df['signal'].rolling(21*24*60).std(ddof=0)
```

Comment: Thank you @CrepeGoat, this adds several orders of magnitude speedups (going from 100 seconds to 0.03 for my dataset)